# If the set of lateral classes $\{\bar{v_1}, ...,\bar{v_n}\}$ of $V/U$ is linearly independent then $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$ over a field $K$. Prove that if the set of lateral classes $\{\bar{v_1}, ...,\bar{v_n}\}$ of $V/U$ is linearly independent then $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is linearly independent.

My attempt:

We know that $\bar{v_j} = v_j+U$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n{\alpha_i\bar{v}_i = 0}$, so, $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\bar{v}_i = \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i(v_i+U) = \sum_{i=1}^n(\alpha_iv_i+U) = (\sum_{i=1}^n(\alpha_iv_i)) + U=0$

And then, I don't know what to do with U.

Comment: You know that the sum of those vectors is in $U$, but the they represent linearly independent vectors in the quotient space, so the only coefficients that satisfy this are zeros. As the zero vector is in $U$, this proves the claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to prove that the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are linearly independent, so, suppose that the zero vector can be written as
$$\mathbf0 = \sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i \quad \textrm{for some scalars } a_1,\dots,a_n.$$
Observe that, the zero vector of $V/U$ is the set $U = \mathbf0 + U$. Since
$$\mathbf0 + U = \Big( \sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i \Big) + U = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i(v_i+U)$$
and the vectors $v_1+U,\dots,v_n+U$ are linearly independent, it follows that $a_1=\cdots=a_n=0$, proving that $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are linearly independent.